# How do I add a worksheet after all existing Excel worksheets?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I need to add an Excel sheet at the end of the current sheet number 3. When I run the below program, however, I get a sheet at the first position. How can I resolve this?

The program basically copies data from one Excel workbook to another workbook, consisting of multiple sheets.

Code:

```
Dim objXL,objWrkBk,objWrkSht,a,n
Set objfso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objXL=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWrkBk=objXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\learning\demo.xlsx")
m=objWrkBk.Worksheets.count
msgbox m
For n=1 to m
Set objWrkBk=objXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\learning\demo.xlsx")
Set objWrkSht=objWrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet"&n)
columncount = objWrkSht.usedrange.columns.count
rowcount = objWrkSht.usedrange.rows.count
For i=1 to rowcount
For j=1 to columncount
If   objWrkSht.cells(i,j).value <> "" Then
    a= objWrkSht.cells(i,j).value& "   "
End If
'Next
'Next
check=objfso.FileExists("C:\learning\demo1.xlsx")
If not check Then
    objXL.Workbooks.Add
    objXL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\learning\demo1.xlsx")
End If
Set objWrkBk1=objXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\learning\demo1.xlsx")
If n<=3 Then
    Set objWrkSht1=objWrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet"&n)
End If
If n>3 Then
    objXL.Worksheets.add
    Set objWrkSht1=objWrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet"&n)
End If

If   objWrkSht.cells(i,j).value <> "" Then
objWrkSht1.cells(i,j).value=a
objWrkBk1.Save
End If
Next
Next
Set objWrkSht=Nothing
Set objWrkBk=Nothing
Set objWrkSht1=Nothing
Set objWrkBk1=Nothing

Next
objXL.Quit
Set objXL=Nothing
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add sheets in the `After` position, ie this code adds the sheet after the last worksheet (provided by `objWrkBk.Sheets(objWrkBk.Sheets.Count))` where  `objWrkBk.Sheets.Count)` is the number of sheets prior to the addition.

```
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWrkBk = objXL.Workbooks.Add
Set objWrkSht = objWrkBk.Sheets.Add(, objWrkBk.Sheets(objWrkBk.Sheets.Count))
```

Comment: + 1 straight and simple :)

Comment: Thank you :) nice to get fast response

Answer (score 0):

seems Worksheets property is read-only

> Returns a Sheets collection that represents all the worksheets in the
>   specified workbook. Read-only Sheets object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835542(v=office.15).aspx

whereas Sheets is the real thing where you can also add Sheets dynamically

> A collection of all the sheets in the specified or active workbook.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193217(v=office.15).aspx