# Programmatically creating worksheets in an Excel Add In (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, button, addition, worksheet

According to MSDN, one can programmatically create and delete Excel Worksheets in Visual Studio (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fczc37s.aspx).  The code to do so is as follows:

```
private void createNewAccount()
{            
    Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
    newWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();            
}
```

One of the forms in my project has a button carrying this code.  The user is supposed to be able to press it and create a new worksheet, but it doesn't work.  So I decided to make it a button on a ribbon tab, instead.  That didn't work either.  What am I missing?

Comment: try to change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not going to be too long.

If you need to go Microsoft way, please first be sure to first create a Book. Remember Excel files resemble a [workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386180.aspx), then, inside, you can create worksheets.

If you don't please take a look at [NPOI project](https://npoi.codeplex.com/).

With both approaches you will have to create the workbook, then the worksheets inside.

[More on this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306022).

Well, If you are sure you have access to a WorkBook I would recommend you to:

1.- Use the parameters of the [WorkSheets.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

2.- Please take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109102/how-do-i-add-a-worksheet-after-all-existing-excel-worksheets).

3.- Persist the workbook after the worksheet is added. This will allow to check if it was added or not.

Last but not least, debug, debug and debug.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I should probably clarify: the project I'm working on is an add in for Excel.  The assumption is that the user can load in this add in and apply it to an existing workbook.  In terms of programming, the workbook already exists under the namespace Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.  I don't have a problem accessing its properties at runtime (I know this because the form I mentioned earlier has a function that populates a list box with the names of all worksheets in the book when the form is loaded).

Comment: @user3352070 see simoco's comment below your original post. I think he has answered it for you