# Adding more than 3 Excel sheets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a project where I need to create 4 different sheets in same Excel workbook.

I'm able to enter data into 3 sheets, but getting error while creating a 4th sheet.

Please help.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466252/programmatically-creating-worksheets-in-an-excel-add-in-c
If it does, this is a duplicate question :)

Comment: Show the code throwing this error and specify exactly what error is. Otherwise noone can help you since there are no mind-readers here.

Comment: Error reading the excel file: Invalid index ( Exception from HRESULT:0x80020000B(DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Comment: So that kind of confirms GvS's answer; but can you please update the original question with this information to make it a more useful question?

Answer (score 2):

The default template of Excel contains 3 worksheets.

If you want to address a 4th, you should add it.

Also note that if you are going to install this software on a user's PC, the template might have changed, so there might be only one worksheet available.

The savest approach is to test the number of availble sheets, and add all you need. Or remove all sheets, and add all yourself.

Comment: Error reading the excel file: Invalid index ( Exception from HRESULT:0x80020000B(DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Comment: @ThejasB, the BADINDEX looks like you immediatly try to access the 4th sheet. Maybe you could post the code.